# How to send message to concrete user id using server-sent events?

Tags: architecture, software-design, server-sent-events

Does server-sent events allow to send message to concrete user by user id? Or it works like fanout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending to the current user is the only choice; it is not a broadcast technology and fan-out is not an option.

Each SSE connection is a dedicated socket for each client. (WebSocket is too.) So if you want to broadcast to more than one client you need to perform extra steps on the server-side (e.g. shared memory, or each process polling a database, etc.)

If you want to send a message to a specific *user id* then it is basically the same. E.g. have one DB record (or shared memory slot) for each user id, and store the message there. If that user id has a SSE connection the server-side process would be polling that particular DB record. Each time it changes it pushes out the new message to the client.